# Redmine: Copy issue multiple times

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

Copying one issue and its child issues is a natively built-in feature and thus works just fine.

But is there a way to do this multiple times?
Like re-creating one issue (including its children) twenty or fifty times?

**Edit 2**

This new functionality should be accessible via the `Redmine` interface and compatible to any browser.

It does not matter whether it is a completely new Plugin, an extension to the built-in copy feature, a call to a `PHP-script` or anything else.
Due to compatibility (networking, browsers etc.) I guess a completely server-side modification is the only way to go here.

What parts of the default plugin (as created in the voting [tutorial](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Plugin_Tutorial)) or a core element would have to be changed?

Where can I find the code for the native issue copy function?

Or - if all this is too complicated - how would I write my plugin to point to a `PHP` file that manipulates the `SQL` database directly?

**Edit**:

To clarify: just like the normal copy function (either in the context menu or the top-right link, I don't care) I want to copy one issue and its sub-issues n times.
To let the user set the amount n, any user number input may suffice, like a textbox, a pop-up etc.

Comment: Do you need a button in the interface of the Redmine to duplicate issue N times or just need to duplicate single (several) issues N times?

Comment: a button (for the action itself) and a text box (for the amount of issues) would be the best i think...
or i just 'extend' the built-in copy function by some textbox someplace and loop that copy function... only thing is: i havent located that function yet...

Comment: Okey, sorry can't help much then. In the later case it's quite trivial to implement either external script or [bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet), which will execute usual Copy function N times for given issue.

Comment: oh wait, sorry. now i fully understand what you meant...
using scripts etc outside of Redmine and not accessible via Redmine would be a last resort... the requirement for that extension is that many users from different systems, different networks, virtual connections and browsers have to be able to accomplish multiplying issues.
if i started implementing it as a bookmarklet, im afraid most users (PEBCAK types) would have problems with that (i.e. acquiring, bookmarking, compatibility, properly executing)

Comment: Exactly. If you have many users to use it, it definitely should be implemented as a Redmine plugin and not as something external.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest way to do this is to start with redmine source modification.
Once it works you can move on and try to extract this feature into plugin.

Note, that I am not a ruby developer, so some things below are just my guesses. But I did few small redmine modifications like this before and hope that my thoughts can be useful.

It will also be easier if you familiar with some of MVC frameworks (for any language), because they mostly have a similar structure with routes, controllers, views and models.

## The Idea

The link to copy single issue looks like this: `//redmine.myserver.com/projects/myapp/issues/12407/copy`.

My idea is to add a `num_copies` parameter to this link and use it in the code to create many copies.

You need no UI for that, once implemented the feature will work like this:

- find the issue you need
- choose the `copy` action for it
- once the form opened, manually add `?num_copies=XX` parameter into the URL (`//redmine.myserver.com/projects/myapp/issues/12407/copy?num_copies=50`) and press 'Enter' to reload the form
- check the details and submit the form - it will create multiple copies according to the `num_copies` parameter

## The Implementation Plan

Now, how to do this.
I am referring to the [redmine mirror on github](https://github.com/redmine/redmine) which looks fresh.

### 1) Find where the `.../copy` link is handled

When you open the form to copy the issue, you'll see form like this:

```
<form action="/projects/myapp/issues" class="new_issue" id="issue-form" method="post">
  <input id="copy_from" name="copy_from" type="hidden" value="12407">
  <div class="box tabular">
    <div id="all_attributes">
      ...
</form>
```

Note the form action, it points to the `/issues` link and it will submit the `copy_from` parameter (this is ID of the issue we are copying).

### 2) Find the code which handles the form submission

We could first go and check through the `config/routes.rb`, but we can just guess that we need the `controllers/issues_controller.rb`

Search for the place where `copy_from` parameter is [used](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/master/app/controllers/issues_controller.rb#L405).

You'll see the `build_new_issue_from_params` method. 
Now search for its usages and you'll find [this](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/master/app/controllers/issues_controller.rb#L26):

```
before_filter :build_new_issue_from_params, :only => [:new, :create]
```

From how it looks, I guess that it is called before both `new` and `create` actions.
Looking at new and create definitions, the `new` action renders the new issue form and the `create` action handles the form post.

### 3) Add the `num_copies` parameter to the form

Find the [view file](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/master/app/views/issues/new.html.erb#L8) used by [new issue action](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/master/app/controllers/issues_controller.rb#L128).
Here there is a template for the new issue form, try to add `num_copies` parameter similar to the [copy_from](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/master/app/views/issues/new.html.erb#L8):

```
<%= title l(:label_issue_new) %>    
<%= call_hook(:view_issues_new_top, {:issue => @issue}) %>    
...
  <%= error_messages_for 'issue' %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'copy_from', params[:copy_from] if params[:copy_from] %>
```

Here I am not 100% sure if it will just work if you add a similar line for `num_copies. You may also need to modify the [route](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/master/config/routes.rb#L124).

When done, you should have the new issue form like this:

```
<form action="/projects/myapp/issues" class="new_issue" id="issue-form" method="post">
  <input id="copy_from" name="copy_from" type="hidden" value="12407">
  <input id="copy_from" name="num_copies" type="hidden" value="50">
  <div class="box tabular">
    <div id="all_attributes">
      ...
</form>
```

### 4) Handle the `num_copies` parameter

It should be done in the [create action](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/master/app/controllers/issues_controller.rb#L135):

```
def create
  ...
  call_hook(:controller_issues_new_before_save, { :params => params, :issue => @issue })
  @issue.save_attachments(params[:attachments] || (params[:issue] && params[:issue][:uploads]))
  if @issue.save
      ...
end
```

Here you already have the `@issue` variable created in the `build_new_issue_from_params` method and what you need to do is to check if `num_copies` parameter is set and if it is set then copy / save the `@issue` in a loop to create additional copies.

I can't provide the exact code snippet for this, but it should not be very complex.
Check [this](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/master/app/controllers/issues_controller.rb#L280) code in the `bulk_update` method, it looks like what you need:

```
issue = orig_issue.copy({},
  :attachments => copy_attachments,
  :subtasks => copy_subtasks,
  :link => link_copy?(params[:link_copy])
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this specific plugin is not high priority for Redmine community. 
But, you can write very easy API calling for Java, Python or other language to do what you exactly want.

Here, you can see API documentation how to list, create, update issues.
[Issue API documentation](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues#Creating-an-issue)

PS: You can leave your request in redmine community, 
maybe you are lucky https://redmine.org/projects/redmine/issues